# Show that the $L^2$ norm of $x_0$ can be arbitrarily larger than the norms of $A$ and $b$. $x_0$ is a solution of $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that $x_0$ is a solution to the following linear system
$Ax = b$
where $A$ is an $n \times m$ matrix, with $n < m$, $x$ is an $m$-dimensional column vector and
$b$ is an $n$-dimensional column vector. Show that the $L^2$ norm of $x_0$ can be arbitrarily larger than the norms of $A$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: is $A$ injective? If not, it has nontrivial kernel, with nonzero vector $q$. Assuming there is a solution at all, let's call it $y$, then what can you say about $x=y+tq$ as $t$ gets arbitrarily large?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the answer.

Comment: Can you give another hint, please?  q is the vector which makes A invertible? 
Why do you add q to y?